How to Create 'Gmail' Service with GoogleCredentials
I have the following versions
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.auth/google-auth-library-oauth2-http -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.auth</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-auth-library-oauth2-http</artifactId>
            <version>1.25.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-gmail</artifactId>
            <version>v1-rev20240520-2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

I am trying to create a Gmail client like so (following https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java):
GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.newBuilder()
                .setAccessToken(
                        AccessToken.newBuilder()
                                .setTokenValue(googleTokenResult.getAccessToken())
                                .setExpirationTime(new Date(googleTokenResult.accessTokenExpirationUnixTime))
                                .setScopes(SCOPES)
                                .build()
                )
                .build();
Gmail service = new Gmail.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credentials)
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();

but I am getting a compilation error because credentials (which is GoogleCredentials not GoogleCredential since GoogleCredential is deprecated) is not of type HttpRequestInitiatlizer.
Does anyone have an example (or know how) I create the gmail service given GoogleCredentials?

The key was to use the following:
HttpRequestInitializer httpRequestInitializer = new HttpCredentialsAdapter(credentials);

